# Django - looks like the wrong pages/html being displayed inside a firewall, but ok outside

Tags: html, django, proxy, firewall

We have just started to deploy our app over four schools with the server located in one school. The Three schools accessing from outside the system are working fine, but when you access from the school hosting the server, its like the wrong HTML is being returned. In one case, a user had a page returned to her with a different users userid displayed on the page. It also keeps going back to the login page even though your still logged in. Outside of the school all's fine.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those problems where it's difficult to pinpoint the cause without actually being there, or having lots more information. My first thought is that maybe you're using ip based virtual hosts and the NAT (Network Address Translation) is interfering with it.

**Edit**: could you tell us what sort of caching you have in place? Users seeing each others “logged in” pages without even logging in themselves is a sign that you're caching things that only authenticated users should see.

Comment: we have memcached on the server, but this has never been an issue before and this only remains an issue in one school. The users cannot interact with the pages, it appears to be copies of pages originally sent to other users

Comment: we cache at a base level, objects, not views